# Java match two strings without last character

Tags: java, regex

I've a URL with path being `/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11` . I want to return true if (optionally) there are 3 digits after decimal instead of 2 e.g `/mypath/check/10.101/-123.112` should return true when matched. Before decimal for both two occurences should be exact match.

To cite some examples :
Success

```
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 = /mypath/check/10.101/-123.112
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 = /mypath/check/10.101/-123.11
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 = /mypath/check/10.10/-123.112
/mypath/check/10.10/123.11 = /mypath/check/10.101/123.112
```

.. and so forth

Failure :

```
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 != /mypath/check/10.121/-123.152
/mypath/check/10.11/-123.11 != /mypath/check/10.12/-123.11
```

The numbers before decimal can include `-` with digits with 1 to 3 numbers.

Comment: What do youu mean exactly by "optionally"? Either you want it to match with exactly 3 digits, exactly 2 digits or either 2 or 3 digits. Which is it?

Comment: Added some examples. Does it make sense?

Comment: It's still not clear. You seem to be asking *two* questions: 1) how do you assert there are 2 or 3 trailing digits, and 2) how do you allow an extra trailing digit to still be "equal". Could you please clarify exactly which single thing you are trying to do?`

Answer (score 0):

***Idea***

Regex subpatterns that shall match optionally are suffixed with the `?` modifier. In your case this applies to the 3rd character after a decimal point.

An equality tests modulo that optional digit may be implemented in matching each occurrence of the context pattern and replacing the optional part within the match with the empty string. After this normalization the strings can be tested for equality.

***Code***

```
// Initializing test data.
// Will compare Strings in batch1, batch2 at the same array position.
//
String[] batch1 = {
        "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11"
      , "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11"
      , "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11"
      , "/mypath/check/10.10/123.11"

      , "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11"
      , "/mypath/check/10.11/-123.11"
    };
String[] batch2 = {
        "/mypath/check/10.101/-123.112"
      , "/mypath/check/10.101/-123.11" 
      , "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.112" 
      , "/mypath/check/10.101/123.112"

      , "/mypath/check/10.121/-123.152"                           
      , "/mypath/check/10.12/-123.11"                           
    };

// Regex pattern used for normalization:
//    - Basic pattern: decimal point followed by 2 or 3 digits
//    - Optional part: 3rd digit of the basic pattern
//    - Additional context: Pattern must match at the end of the string or be followed by a non-digit character.
//
Pattern re_p = Pattern.compile("([.][0-9]{2})[0-9]?(?:$|(?![0-9]))");

// Replacer routine for processing the regex match. Returns capture group #1
Function<MatchResult, String> fnReplacer= (MatchResult m)-> { return m.group(1); };


// Processing each test case
// Expected result
//    match
//    match
//    match
//    match
//    mismatch
//    mismatch
//
for ( int i = 0; i < batch1.length; i++ ) {
    String norm1 = re_p.matcher(batch1[i]).replaceAll(fnReplacer);
    String norm2 = re_p.matcher(batch2[i]).replaceAll(fnReplacer);

    if (norm1.equals(norm2)) {
        System.out.println("Url pair #" + Integer.toString(i) + ": match ( '" + norm1 + "' == '" + norm2 + "' )");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Url pair #" + Integer.toString(i) + ": mismatch ( '" + norm1 + "' != '" + norm2 + "' )");
    }
}
```

Demo available [here (ideone.com)](https://ideone.com/rV5Mc6).

Comment: Shouldn't this include an anchor to match the end of string?

Comment: How do i match based on the 2 strings? One with extra digit after decimal and one without

Comment: @RichardJessop As I understand the requirements, the optional digit may occur in any path component (not just the last). Thus the end anchor would occur in an alternation branch at best. However, I do have misread the requirements at another place. Will post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/mypath/check/10\.10/-?123\.11[ ]*=[ ]*/mypath/check/(\d\d)\.\1\d?/`
[demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGdWyn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 url1.equals(url2) || url1.equals(url2.replaceAll("\\d$", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the first URL always has exactly 2 digits after every decimal point. If so, match the 2nd URL to the regex formed by appending an optional digit to the end of each decimal fraction in the first URL.

```
static boolean matchURL(String url1, String url2)
{
    return url2.matches(url1.replaceAll("([.][0-9]{2})", "$1[0-9]?"));      
}
```

Test:

```
String url1 = "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11";

List<String> tests = Arrays.asList(
        "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11",
        "/mypath/check/10.10/-123.111",
        "/mypath/check/10.101/-123.11",
        "/mypath/check/10.101/-123.111",
        "/mypath/check/10.11/-123.11"
        );

for(String url2 : tests)
    System.out.format("%s : %s = %b%n", url1, url2, matchURL(url1, url2));
```

Output:

```
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 : /mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 = true
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 : /mypath/check/10.10/-123.111 = true
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 : /mypath/check/10.101/-123.11 = true
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 : /mypath/check/10.101/-123.111 = true
/mypath/check/10.10/-123.11 : /mypath/check/10.11/-123.11 = false
```